# setImageWithURL in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

In `AFNetworking 1.x`, we could use `setImageWithURL` in a way like this:

```
NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:IdPhoto isThumb:NO];
[photoView setImageWithURL: imageURL];
}
```

where `IdPhoto` is the Id of the Photo I am trying to load into an image view.

This code doesn't work in `AFNetworking 2.0`. I think I have to use an `AFImageResponseSerializer` in some way, but can't figure out how exactly to write the code.

Thanks

Comment: It should work, why do you say it doesn’t? What is the error?

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector setImageWithURL. PhotoView is my imageView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this code work, you need to import `<UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>`

Comment: It seems like that should work, but XCode says that the file is not found when I try to import it. Any idea why?

Comment: Also, I believe when you import AFNetworking.h, the file would be already imported for the UIImageView. I have imported AFNetworking.h and it is still not working.

Comment: Make sure the AFNetworking you are using includes the UIKit additions.

Comment: Thanks, I just had to add the folder for the UIKit AFNetworking files.